# Selectbox not allow user to select other option if condition met

Tags: javascript, selection

May i know how can i make select box cannot select other options if condition is met? Not disabled function, is like when select items from selectbox if the script condition is met, it will automatically revert back to the previous selected option.

```
<%
 Vector vTable = (Vector) session.getAttribute("TABLE_CERT");  
%>
<script>
function rateStatus()
{
    if(<%=vTable.size()%> > 0)
    {
        //what condition should i put in here??
    }
}
</script>
 <select name="RATE_TYPE" onChange="rateStatus()" >
               <option value="T" <% if (RATE_TYPE.equals("T") ){out.println("selected");} %>> Tariff </option>
               <option value="SE" <% if (RATE_TYPE.equals("SE") ){out.println("selected");} %>> Self </option>
               <option value="SP" <% if (RATE_TYPE.equals("SP") ){out.println("selected");} %>> Special </option>
 </select>
```

Comment: [HTMLSelectElement Interface](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement) contains all the information you need for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can intercept onChange event (you are handling it with `rateStatus`) and restore `.defaultValue` when you need it

```
<script>
function rateStatus(el)
{
    if(<%=vTable.size()%> > 0)
    {
        el.value = el.defaultValue;
    }
}
</script>
<select name="RATE_TYPE" onChange="rateStatus(this)" >
               <option value="T" <% if (RATE_TYPE.equals("T") ){out.println("selected");} %>> Tariff </option>
               <option value="SE" <% if (RATE_TYPE.equals("SE") ){out.println("selected");} %>> Self </option>
               <option value="SP" <% if (RATE_TYPE.equals("SP") ){out.println("selected");} %>> Special </option>
 </select>
```

Comment: hi, sorry, Could you show the way ? for the script part?

Comment: try the modified version of my answer

Answer (score 0):

> Not disabled function, is like when select items from selectbox if the
>   script condition is met, it will automatically revert back to the
>   previous selected option.

Based on your question text, let me add another answer, this might be the behaviour what you are looking for:

```
$("#selectBox").attr('onfocus', 'this.defaultIndex=this.selectedIndex;');
$("#selectBox").attr('onchange', 'this.selectedIndex=this.defaultIndex');
```

See here: http://jsfiddle.net/ddan/jvu5w6zn/3/

If condition met, anything you select, it jumps back to original selection.

Comment: @user3835327 Is this the solution you were looking for?